# JSON slashes and backslashes in string on bourne shell

Tags: json, string, escaping, sh, jq

I am trying to parse json files that contain sequences of slashes and backslashes in some of their strings like this:

```
echo '{"tag_string":"/\/\/\ test"}' | jq
```

which gives me:

```
parse error: Invalid escape at line 1, column 27
```

I have tried escaping with backslashes at different positions, but I can't seem to find a correct way. How do I output the string as it is, without removing any character or getting errors?

This only works on bash, but not sh (or zsh):

```
echo '{"tag_string":"/\\/\\/\\ test"}' | jq -r '.tag_string'
/\/\/\ test
```

Comment: So have you tried to look at what `echo` returns?

Comment: @zerkms no problems with echo: `{"tag_string":"/\/\/\ test"}`

Comment: What does "no problems" mean? My point was for you to get what it outputs and see that it's not valid JSON. Take whatever it returns and put into any JSON validator for details.

Comment: @zerkms I meant by "no problem", this is what I want the final output to be, I already know it's not valid JSON. jsonlint gives me: `Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '[', got 'undefined'`, and I'm asking how those characters must be escaped to not have an error.

Comment: @ae701 - Your problem description is very confusing because on the one hand you indicate you have some "JSON files", but on the other hand, your examples are tangled up with shell issues.  Do you have JSON files, or are you trying to convert some non-JSON files to JSON? ...

Comment: @peak I have huge JSON files that wouldn't work with jq due to this "/\/\/\" pattern, I posted the echos because I was trying to deal with the issue with them instead of using (and posting) the large and confusing files every time. The issue was with the shell in the end, be it the files or by echo.

Comment: @ae701 - If the file contains strings such as "\/" then it's not JSON.  Thus based on your description, the problem would seem to be how to convert a non-JSON file to JSON.

Comment: Technically, it's not `\/` that is the problem, it's the backslashed space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to include literal backslashes:

#### (bash)

```
echo '{"tag_string":"/\\/\\/\\ test"}' | jq
{
  "tag_string": "/\\/\\/\\ test"
}

echo '{"tag_string":"/\\/\\/\\ test"}' | jq -r '.["tag_string"]'
/\/\/\ test
```

#### (sh)

```
echo '{"tag_string":"/\\\\/\\\\/\\\\ test"}' | jq -r '.["tag_string"]'
/\/\/\ test

printf "%s" '{"tag_string":"/\\/\\/\\ test"}' | jq -r '.["tag_string"]'
/\/\/\ test
```

Comment: This fails with the same message: `parse error: Invalid escape at line 1, column 27`, and `Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '[', got 'undefined'` from npm's jsonlint

Comment: Edit: this actually works on bash, but not sh, which is the shell I'm using for my scripts.

Answer (score 2):

A forward slash character is legal, but a single backslash character is not.  According to [json.org](http://json.org) char description, the valid chars are:

```
char
    any-Unicode-character-
        except-"-or-\-or-
        control-character
    \"
    \\
    \/
    \b
    \f
    \n
    \r
    \t
    \u four-hex-digits
```

So in your example, the single backslashes are not legal, you need either "\\" which is interpreted as double backslashes, or you need to remove them entirely.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to convert a file with non-JSON strings, then consider a tool such as any-json. Using the "cson-to-json" mode, "\/" will be interpreted as "/":

```
$ any-json -format=cson
```

Input:

```
{"tag_string":"/\/\/\ test"}
```

Output:

```
{
  "tag_string": "/// test"
}
```